# Find records modified from a date when no date modified column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm sure there isn't but I was hoping somebody could help me to work out if there's a way that I can see when a table last had a record added to it (only historically with no table modifications being made for future instances, I've already added triggers to the tables for future issues).

We're at the mercy of the historical work of others and unfortunately one of these pieces of work involved not using a datemodified field on many of our tables. I now need to check our schema to find potential tables to de-commission and would like to know if there's a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're effectively SOL, but if "close is good enough", look at the `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` and specifically the `last_user_update` column.  That'll tell you the last time something happened that mucked with that index.  If you filter to only Primary Key indexes, then that *generally* means inserted rows.

```
select 
so.name, si.name, us.last_user_update
from  sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats us
inner join sys.objects so
    on so.object_id = us.object_id
inner join sys.indexes si
    on  si.index_id = us.index_id
    and si.object_id = us.object_id
where si.is_primary_key = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use sql server metadata to get this information:

```
SELECT
    [name],
    create_date,
    modify_date
FROM sys.tables
ORDER BY
    modify_date DESC
```

Have a look at this for more detailed guides: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sql+table+last+modified

Comment: In MS SQL, the "modify_date" (really part of sys.objects, but is exposed through sys.table) tells you when the last ALTER statement occurred on the table - ie, any metadata.  Nothing about the contents of rows in the table.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx